# Dyamically set the PARAM Type for PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a loop that allocates values to all params set within a bind param. My problem is I'm not quite sure how to dynamically set the param type when I bind them.

For instance, here is the loop:

```
foreach(array_combine($cols,$vals) as $col => $val) {
    $f->bindParam(':'.$col,$val,PDO::PARAM_INT); // loop through columns and values array and bind those params
}
```

however - if $vals contains a string for one of the values in the array, this breaks (obviously).

How do I set the PARAM_INT dynamically depending on the type of value in $vals?

I've considered using gettype() but that seemed like it would be messy and ugly... :)

Comment: Like [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php)'s PhP manual states, you do not have to put the third agrument which is optional. The function will figures out itself the type to set in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with binding at all - just send everything right into execute:

```
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array_combine($cols,$vals));
```

Don't forget to turn emulation mode off though, as otherwise this method will choke on LIMIT clause parameters.

however, keep in mind that such a dynamical query building you are trying to implement is [prone to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example) and apply the the appropriate protection.

Comment: Thanks YCS - I see now that I can just pass an array into the execute( ) and I see I am overcomplicating this. Now I'm able to pass this in, but it returns a boolean instead of an object I can call with fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). What am I missing?

Comment: I worked it out - needed to do this:
$f = $c->prepare($q->ConstructPrepared());
$f->execute($vals);

$r = $f->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);